# Kernel 3.0.0-1 and NVIDIA driver boot problems

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, nvidia, linux-kernel

I can't boot kernel 3.0.0-1 on Asus G53S running Debian, it freezes when booting with:

```
NVRM loading NVIDIA Unix x86_64 kernel module 275.28
```

then it times out with:

```
udevd[350]: timeout: killing 'usb_id --export /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/video4linux/videob' [994]
```

and eventually restarts. This seems like a problem with NVIDIA proprietary driver, yet the message from dkms suggested it got configured fine when installing new kernel headers. Also why doesn't it just drop to shell if it cannot load the nvidia driver module? I'm stuck with an old 2.6.32 kernel and I was really hoping for some of the goodies coming with 3.0 (asus wmi driver especially). Both the kernel and NVIDIA driver are coming from repositories.

Comment: This won't answer your question (sorry), I just want to say that when I had trouble with the nvidia/dkms stuff the last time, I gave nouveau another try and I have never looked back since.

Comment: Not an option unfortunately, this is a CUDA development linux box. Besides I'm not 100% sure if the driver is here to blame...

Comment: Why not the latest driver from the Nvidia website ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't I need first to install the kernel, boot it without X server and then run the binary they provide?

Comment: do you use a framebuffer? if so, is nvidia module for framebuffer loaded? it is incompatible with X driver, and needs to be unloaded/blacklisted.